# After installing Delphi 11.3 to a new laptop I am getting signature error as I compile my apk in development mode

Tags: delphi, signature, conflict

Does anyone knows why I am getting signature error ( App not installed as package conflicts with an existing package) after I have installed Delphi 11.3 to a new laptop and compiled the project and deployed to the device directly.

I know if I uninstall the app it will work but that is something, I don't want to do it as I have several copies already installed and they do regular update through my server rather than play store.

Not: I have a signature file but did do what it was supposed to do on Development mode deploy.

Any answer really appreciated.

Thanks